# update-cart and checkout buttons merge

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have WooCommerce specific question.

I have update-cart button:

```
<input class="popcart-buy-btn" type="submit" action="CHECKOUT URL" name="update_cart" value="Pirkti"/>
```

How to make it to redirect to checkout AFTER cart update? Right now, if there are changes in cart, I need to click on it, wait it for update product pricing, and then click again. How to get these to work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty stupid, but working workaround with javascript:

```
$(".popcart-buy-btn").click(function(){ 
           function show_popup(){
              $('.popcart-buy-btn').click();
           };
           window.setTimeout( show_popup, 1000 );
      });
```